# Axiom of choice : continuous function and uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, axiom-of-choice, uniform-continuity

How I proof that every continuous function f in [0,1] is uniformly continuous, without axiom o choice?

I took this from the book Axiom of Choice from Horst Herrilich

[image: every continuous function f:[0,1] -> R is uniformly continuous]

He had a observation that indicates a a proof without axiom of choice but i still dont get it how

Comment: Do you already know a proof that does use the axiom of choice? If you sketch that, it would be easier to see how the use of AC might be eliminated.

Comment: The proof that I know builds a family of open subsets of $[0,1]$ and then it uses the compacity to take a finite subfamily. As far as I know, this does not involve the axiom of choice.

Comment: Exactly where is the AC used?

Comment: I think compactness of $[0,1]$ can just be adopted by AC

Comment: I edit the comment

Answer (score 2):

The proof given uses choice to select a $\delta_x$ for each $x\in[0,1]$. However, this can be avoided, for the combination of two reasons:

1. For every $x$ it is possible to select a *rational* $\delta_x$ with the desired property.
2. Even without the axiom of choice there exists a choice function for (nonemepty) subsets of $\mathbb Q$: Since $\mathbb Q$ is known to be countable, take your favorite injection $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb N$ and map each subset of $\mathbb Q$ to the element that has the *smallest* image under your injection.

Because of (2) you don't need to choose each $\delta_x$ *arbitrarily*: you can define a *deterministic* way to choose each $\delta_x$ given $x$, $\varepsilon$ and $f$. If you extend the proof to specify that this deterministic selection of $\delta_x$ is to be used, there is no need for the axiom of choice anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that shrinking $\delta_x$ cannot hurt. So we can shrink it to some $\frac1n$ for an appropriately large $n$ without it damaging the proof in any way.